# Why does using the Seek method in VLC's DBus give so many errors?

Tags: bash, vlc, dbus

I've been trying to use DBus to control VLC and I've managed to get everything working fine but the Seek function that "works" but gives me a ton of errors.

Vlc starting with -v flag and Youtube url link:

```
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
[01623920] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0159ab58] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[01623920] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[61d1b068] mp4 demux warning: elst box found
[61d1b068] mp4 demux warning: STTS table of 1 entries
[61d1b068] mp4 demux warning: CTTS table of 33045 entries
[61d1b068] mp4 demux warning: STTS table of 1 entries
[6157f788] mmal_codec decoder: VCSM init succeeded: Legacy
[615f5710] faad decoder warning: decoded zero sample
[62602618] gles2 generic error: parent window not available
[62602130] mmal_xsplitter vout display error: Failed to open Xsplitter:opengles2 module
[62602618] xcb generic error: window not available
[62602130] mmal_xsplitter vout display error: Failed to open Xsplitter:xcb_x11 module
```

VLC log when I try to use Seek:

`[62602618] mmal_vout generic warning: Unsupported control query 4
[6157f788] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[016295c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 43 ms)
[01615ae0] main audio output warning: playback too late (61289): up-sampling
[01615ae0] main audio output warning: timing screwed (drift: 125557 us): stopping resampling
[01615ae0] main audio output warning: playback too late (134644): up-sampling
[01615ae0] main audio output warning: playback way too late (185671): flushing buffers
[01615ae0] pulse audio output warning: starting late (-13368 us)
[01615ae0] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-562329): playing silence
[01615ae0] main audio output warning: playback too late (63592): up-sampling
[01615ae0] main audio output warning: playback way too late (316071): flushing buffers
[01615ae0] pulse audio output warning: starting late (-11502 us)
[01615ae0] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-724374): playing silence
[01615ae0] main audio output warning: playback too late (64426): up-sampling*`

I'm using vlc for youtube streaming and the DBus call is:

```
function omxdbus {
   dbus-send --type=method_call --reply-timeout=550 -- 
   dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 $*
}
omxdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Seek int64:$offset >/dev/null
```

Offset being time in microseconds (im using 10 000 000 to skip 10sec).
Everything is running on Raspbian lite on a Raspberry 2b. I've searched a lot for the problem but nothing shows up. (Note: vlc is actually able to jump the 10 sec just fine (1/2 sec delay)).

Thanks in advance!